# Should we rely on the user to complete an action?

Tags: user-behavior, incentives

So we are thinking of creating a rewards system in our app. For example, there would be a parent and a child both with our app. If the child completes a task correctly (ex. getting off internet 30 minutes early) then the parents can reward their child as many points as they want. Then the child can redeem those points for rewards, such as a new toy, which the parent would have to go out and buy. The idea is to improve communication/relations between the two individuals, but I feel that relying on the "parent" to both give points and give rewards are just asking for incorrect use. (ex. parent giving child an excess amount of points for being good, but never rewards child when they try to redeem.)

Do you think it is a good idea to rely on users to give/reward each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, reading the statement of the application, what surprised me the most was what you later questioned: –*can reward their child as many points as they want*–. I think this can not only be a new source of conflict but also in a certain sense discredits your application: what's the use of having the application if then I am the one who has to decide as a parent how many points to give the child?

I would try to adjust the system by making some rules, this will even favor the credibility of the application and consequently will encourage the future user to use it. For example,

- Establish a set of rewards based on tokens, 1, 2, 3, and 5..., where
  a parent can decide based on the level of sacrifice made or they can previously agree together
- Set groups of tokens to get for a possible trade, for example, 1st
  redeemable group 60 tokens, 120 tokens, 300 tokens
- Each of these groups have a possible purchasable object so that
  the child has a tangible objective and can manage his/her efforts. For
  example 120 tokens = a mini lego or a barbie, 300 tokens = 1 electric
  skateboard.
- The application has its own token design (without becoming a
  cryptocurrency!)
- The participants, regardless of the relationship, should have a visible
  board of the transactions progresses and they can verify it
  personally or together.
- The board should show the individual tokens and the group tokens with
  arrival stops, the gamification helps both participants.
- Allow the child (in the case of the example of the question) to
  decide what top he/she wants to reach. They will have to manage
  what compensates them more, having five times the minimum group or
  only once a high group.

Well, generally speaking, let the app be a decision aid rather than a liberal transaction.

**Edit after the comment:**

–*How this will solve the issue with parents being able to award as many points as they want?*–

- Setting groups of tokens as written before, with not very high quantities and not allowing to acquire more than one group per challenge.

–*Is there a way to fix the source of conflict between two users when one of them doesn't follow through with their promise of a reward?*–

- I don't know if the application has a real credit, if so, the one who offers the reward must make a deposit for the group of tokens that have been assigned to the challenge, activate it at the start time, and with the possibility of canceling or validating once finished. (We get in specific modes of use of the application).
- If one of the parties does not fulfill the obligation, in the case of the child it's easy to verify the father has not validated the deposit made. In the case of the father, each group of tokens should have a time limit, with follow-up, alerts, and responses, to both sides.
- If the deposits are validated, the application will know that the transaction has been carried out correctly.
- The application can impose a limit of up to three wrong or incorrect transactions, and from there, a warning or a time without being able to participate in the application.

<sub>*You will understand that this is all conjecture, I am not involved in the project*</sub>

Comment: I like the general idea, it is very similar to what our final product will be. I am curious how this will solve the issue with parents being able to award as many points as they want? Also, is there a way to fix the source of conflict between two users when one of them doesn't follow through with their promise of a reward?

Comment: Answer updated.–

Comment: very interesting answer, probably much more than what this site is supposed to (you gave the OP a high value business plan!). But as we're at it: why not crypto? it sounds like a perfect scenario for a stable crypto

Comment: Great answer! I think the visibility between transactions will have a big impact in preventing any issues with relying on the user. I also like the idea of the app validating each transaction

Comment: @Devin "stable crypto", does this exist? 